# ABP 8 build errors when we use packages source code

Tags: abp

I am using ABP version 8, when I replace package with source code using ABP suite then I started getting build errors.
`dotnet restore` command is also failed and throwing error.

[image]

Looks like the problem is with the .csproj file
E.g

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup><LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Admin.Application</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Admin.Application</PackageId>
    <RootNamespace />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Shared.Application\Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Shared.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Admin.Application.Contracts\Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Admin.Application.Contracts.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Commercial.Core" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here `Volo.Abp.Commercial.Core` code is not downloaded by abp suite when I replace packages with source code but in the `Volo.Abp.Account.Pro.Admin.Application.csproj`
project file it's like this that's the reason it's not able to restore the package.
if I write like below then it's started working.. but I don't want to do in each project file and do it manually it will take lots of time. Is it the issue with ABP? anyone facing same issue ?

[image]